# How to connect multiple android mobile devices over mobile network?

Tags: android, networking, mobile, connectivity

Is it possible to connect multiple mobile devices over mobile network without using server/Wifi? I am developing application for live video streaming. Anybody having any idea kindly share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you're looking at video streaming, I'll just step up to the plate and kindly say "no, there are no video steraming / screencasting capabilities without an internet connection or a shared connection". Bluetooth does not have the required bandwidth for decent streaming.

Comment: Shark, I need to connect the devices using mobile network data only. Not using wifi/server.

Comment: You're not going to be able to stream video that way, but maybe you can stream a slideshow of pictures... So please prove me wrong, and find/develop a way.

Comment: @Shark is it possible to send/receive messages over mobile network without using any server

Comment: @UserAndroid only MMS and SMS messages. Push notifications require you to have internet.

Comment: @Shark I need to send messages using mobile internet (2g or 3g ) not SMS or MMS

Comment: And what kind of "message" would that be? And why aren't you asking that in a separate question instead of a different question's comments?